# how to select elements by tag name only within a specified div

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make a simple slide show to cycle through my images. The problem I'm having is when trying to select only the images in the "image_wrapper" div using `document.getElementById("image_wrapper").getElementsByTagName("img")`
is that it also selects the images from a sibling div. I only want to cycle through the images in the image_wrapper div.

The html `onclick` calls `addOne()` when the right arrow is clicked, and `takeOne()` when the left arrow is clicked

```
var x = 0;

var hideImage = document.getElementsByClassName("profile_image");           
function displayOne() {
    for(i = 0; i < hideImage.length; i++) {
      if(i == 0) {
        hideImage[0].style.display = "inline-block";
      }
    }
}

function addOne() {
    var profileImg = document.getElementById("image_wrapper").getElementsByTagName("img");
    if(x < profileImg.length ) {
        x++; 
    } else {
      x = 0;
    }
    for(i = 0; i < profileImg.length ; i++) {
      if(x == profileImg.length) { x = 0;}
      if(x == i) {
          profileImg[i].style.display = "inline-block";
      } else {
        profileImg[i].style.display = "none";
      }
    }
}

function takeOne() {
    var profileImg = document.getElementById("image_wrapper").getElementsByTagName("img");
    if(x > 0 ) {
      x--; 
    } else {
      x += profileImg.length - 1 ;
    }
    for(i = 0; i < profileImg.length ; i++) {
      if(x == -1) { x = profileImg.length; }
      if(x == i) {
        profileImg[i].style.display = "inline-block";
      } else {
        profileImg[i].style.display = "none";
      }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried;

```
document.querySelectorAll('#image_wrapper img');
```

[document.querySelectorAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) and [document.querySelector()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) can take css selectors.